# Will this for loop run infinitely?

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf

I have some experience with the c programming but sometimes the author of some books just pose such strange syntactical question which we will never use in actual programming and similar to that I stuck on one such question though the answer is given but I am not able to understand the answer.Here is the code below

```
int main
{
int i;
for(;scanf("%d",&i);printf("%d",i)){
     ;
    }
}
```

The question is how many times this for loop will run and the answer given is indefinite
Can anyone explain how the loop will get executed

Comment: Hint: what if `scanf()` fails? did you check the return value then?

Comment: The code won't compile (`int main` has a problem)

Comment: Yes I forgot to write return statement. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scanf` returns number of elements successfully read and in this case it will be 1 if it reads a integer and keeps printing it.

Let's say you pass a character here then `scanf()` fails and exits from a `for` loop

Comment: Hey I still have this one doubt The prototype of scanf() is **int scanf(const char * format, ...);** It reads the data from stdin and stores the data in the location specified by the additional arguments in the format specified by the format specifier and returns the no of items successfully read. So even if it is reading a character in the above case it will store that character as an integer which will i guess may be return 0 or whatever but it will read the character wont it then why does the loop stops when it reads the character ?

Comment: @RohitSaluja There is something called matching sequence in `scanf()` your passed data and the data-type to which the the value is scanned should be same else you might see something being written to the variable but the C standard says using wronf format specifier lead to undefined behavior and must be avoided in the code.So scanf() will return number of successfull matches happend and this case successfull conversion didn't happen as the format specifier was weong. If this as answered your question mark it as answered

Comment: But then why if i use something like <br/>  int i,p;
    p=scanf("%c",&i);
    printf("The value of p = %d\n",p);   here if i enter i as an integer or even as a character p always returns 1 why so ?

Comment: @RohitSaluja Yes that is fine because .. the input even if it is a integer is stored as a character the value say you passed is 5 then it will be stored as '5'..  The conversion passed because 5 is a valid character you get it right? with ASCII value of 53

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing the doubt Gopi well sometimes it really gets frustrating when I see unexpected behavior and then have to refer to experts like you. I don't know when will I able to reach that level :/

Comment: @RohitSaluja I am no expert .. :) :)

Answer (score 3):

Scanf will return the no of successful input get. If you give the input correctly then the condition will be true so it keep on running as indefinite.

To make the condition false you can give the input other than the integer value. That time scanf will return zero. So the loop will end.

Answer (score 2):

Here, indefinite means that it is cannot be defined(unknown), it does not mean infinite (just to clear things out). Because, here the no of times the loop is run is dependent on the input given. If a correct input is given, which is an integer, the loop keeps running. If a wrong input is given, that is a non integer, the control jumps out of the loop. So you cant have a single answer for all scenarios, hence it is indefinite.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is not an infinite `for` loop.

As per the syntax of `for` loop, from section 6.8.5.3 of the [n1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) TC3 C99

> **for** **(** *clause-1* ; *expression-2* ; *expression-3* **)** *statement*
>
> behaves as follows: The expression expression-2 is the controlling expression that is
>   evaluated before each execution of the loop body....

In your case, *expression-2* is `scanf("%d",&i)`, and the return value of `scanf()` will be considered for evaluation of  *expression-2*.

As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) of `scanf()`

> ### Return Value
>
> ... return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.

So, in your case,

- till time `scanf()` is success, it will `number of input items
  successfully matched`, which is `1` and a `TRUE` value, `for` loop
  will continue execution.
- if the `scanf()` fails [example: input `char` value], the return
  value of `scanf()` will be `0` [matching failure] and the loop will
  terminate.

Answer (score 0):

After accept answer

---

Yes this very well may be an infinite loop.

`scanf()` returns the number of successfully scanned fields (0 or 1 ) here or `EOF` on IO error or end-of-file.

The *only* way to exit the loop is to enter a non-numeric input like "xyz".

Should user close `stdin`, `scanf()` will return `EOF`.  `EOF` is a negative value (not 0).  So the loop will continue calling `scanf()`, continue receiving `EOF` until the program is killed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int i;
  for (; scanf("%d", &i); printf("%d", i)) {
    ;
  }
  return 0;
}
```